# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha actual en una determinada zona horaria en R?

Tags: r, powerbi

Necesito recuperara la fecha actual de la zona horaria de la ciudad de México utilizando **R**, solo pude encontrar la fecha del ordenador con un `Sys.Date()`, esto es para colocarlo en un reporte de `Power BI`.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma es usar las clásicas rutinas `Sys.time()` o `Sys.Date()` pero configurando previamente la zona horaria, por ejemplo:

```
# Configuramos la zona horaria local
Sys.setenv(TZ = "")
Sys.time(); Sys.Date(); Sys.timezone()
[1] "2018-02-14 15:44:20 -03"
[1] "2018-02-14"
[1] "America/Buenos_Aires"

# Configuramos una zona horaria en particular
Sys.setenv(TZ = "America/Mexico_City")
Sys.time(); Sys.Date(); Sys.timezone()
[1] "2018-02-14 12:44:20 CST"
[1] "2018-02-14"
[1] "America/Mexico_City"
```

La lista completa de los "Timezones" la puedes buscar en la [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Otra forma podría ser trabajar con una fecha del tipo `POSIXct` con una determinada zona horaria y luego modifcar este atributo

```
Hoy <- as.POSIXct(Sys.time(), tz="America/Buenos_Aires")
Hoy
[1] "2018-02-14 15:56:53 -03"    
attributes(Hoy)$tzone = "America/Mexico_City"
Hoy
[1] "2018-02-14 12:56:53 CST"
```